# Como cambiar un elemento de estilo con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un fullscreen pero tengo un problema ya que no sé como cambiar el valor que viene desde css.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer click el video que no esta visible se pueda ver pero fullscreen. Se que deberia cambiar el DOM con `innerHTML`, pero no sé como hacerlo bien.

HTML

```
<div id="video">Ver Video</div>


<div id="videoBox">
    <video muted autoplay loop controls>
        <source src="assets/video/uno.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#videoBox {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const bt1 = document.getElementById("video");
const bt2 = document.getElementById("close");

bt1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("videoBox").requestFullscreen();
});
```

Espero haber sido claro y agradezco de antemano la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar propiedades css con js puedes usar la propiedad `style` de los elementos HTML:

```
bt1.style.display = 'block' // O el valor que le quieras poner
```

[Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) puedes ver una lista de las propiedades de `style` a las que puedes acceder.

Comment: Gracias camilo, pero no logro que se vea el video al hacer click